# I tried to define x' as x' = x/2, but the character ' is not possible as it seems, What character can I use?

Tags: fonts

Please tell me how denote x_prime as in x'

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should add a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) to precise your question. If you're just trying to write ``x'``, why not writing ``x'`` in the code?

Comment: The crystal ball says you didn't enter math mode; you can do something like $x'=x/2$ to enter a small equation. If that's not the issue then we will need more information in order to provide help.

Comment: There is also \prime if your 16bit characters are not being translated correctly.